# Verifying Proof: If $L$ is a poset with a bottom element, and $\exists \sup(S)$ for every subset $S \subset L$, then $L$ is a complete lattice

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, self-learning, order-theory

I am currently working through [Kaplansky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821826948) for self study and was hoping to get some feedback on this proof. I would appreciate comments on clarity and legability as well.

**Claim:** If $L$ is a poset with a bottom element, and $\exists \sup(S)$ for every subset $S \subset L$, then $L$ is a complete lattice.

**Proof**: Let $0 \in L$ be the bottom element and consider some subset $S \subset L$. We construct the set of lower bounds:
$$
S' = \{l \in L \mid s \in S \implies l \leq s \}.
$$

Clearly, $0 \in S'$ since $\forall l \in L$ we have $0 \leq l \implies \inf(S') = 0$. Additionally, notice that $\exists \sup(S')$ by virtue of the fact that every subset of $L$ has a suprememum. Because $S'$ consists of all lower bounds of $S$, it must be the case that $\sup(S') = \inf(S)$, since any lower bound of $S$ must be in $S'$, and $s' \leq \sup(S')$ $\forall s' \in S'$. Thus, $S$ has an infimum.

Since every subset of $L$ has an $\inf$ and $\sup$, it must be the case that $\forall a,b \in L$, $\exists \sup(\{a,b\})$ and $\exists \inf(\{a,b\})$. Thus, $L$ is a lattice.

$\therefore L$ is a complete lattice.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: It is generally not the case that $a\le b$ for arbitrary $a,b\in S$. Also, your definition of $S'$ makes it equal to $S$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ah, yes. The poset condition is just that the symbol is reflexive, transitive, or antisymmetric?

As for the definition of $S'$, I'm trying to construct the set of all lower bounds, which I believe is possible. Can I modify it such that $S' = \{ s \in S \mid s \leq \sup(S) \; \text{and} \; s \neq \sup(S) \}$?

Comment: If $S'$ is to be the set of lower bounds of $S$, then your definition of $S'$ is wrong. For example, if $a,b \in S$ are not comparable, then $a,b < \sup S$, but $a \nleq b$ and $b \nleq a$, so $a,b$ are not lower bounds of $S$. You should define $S'$ as $$\{x \in L : s \in S \Rightarrow x\leq s\}.$$

Comment: @amrsa Makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: The assumption is probably that $0 \in L$ exists and $\sup S$ for all non-empty subsets of $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $L$ is a complete lattice, we need to show that every subset $A$ of $L$ has a supremum and an infimum.

If $A = \emptyset$, then $\sup A = \bot$, the bottom element (all elements of $L$ are upper bounds of $\emptyset$, voidly, and the minimum, so $\bot$ (or $0$ if you prefer, more Boolean algebra style), while $\inf \emptyset = \max L = \top$ or $1$ which also exists as $\sup L$ itself.

For all other $A$, $\sup A$ aready exists in $L$ by assumption and for the inf, we need to consider (indeed) the set of lower bounds for $A$. This is defined as

$$L(A)=\{x \in L\mid \forall a \in A: x \le a\}$$

and is non-empty as $0 \in L(A)$ for any $A$. So $s=\sup L(A)$ exists in $L$ and I claim it is $\inf A$: if $a \in A$ then $a$ is **an** upperbound for $L(A)$ by definition, and as $\sup L(A)$ is the *minimal* upperbound for $L(A)$, $s \le a$ and as $a \in A$ was arbitrary, $s$ is a lower bound for $A$. Now, if $b$ is any other lower bound for $A$, then $b \in L(A)$ and so $b \le \sup L(A)=s$ and so $s$ is the maximal lowerbound for $A$, i.e. $s=\inf A$.

It follows that all subsets of $L$ have an infimum too. QED